# How get all the objects in a polymorphic nested relationship in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have the following classes

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities
  has_many :products, as: :geography
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :neighborhoods
  has_many :products, as: :geography
end

class Neighborhood < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, as: :geography
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :geography, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
end
```

And obviously I have another `class` `User`.  The user just has permissions for see the `products` in his/her `state` (except if the user is `admin`, in which case he/she can see all the `products`) How I can get all the products of a `User`?

I tried to add some `has_many, :through` to `State` as follows

```
has_many :cities_activities, through: :cities, source: :products

has_many :neighborhoods_activities, through: :neighborhoods, source: :products

def owned_activities
  self.products + self.cities_activities + self.neighborhoods_activities
end
```

but `owned_activities` returns an `Array` not a `ActiveRecord::Relation` (I need some way of return a `ActiveRecord::Relation`, so I can apply on it `chained scopes`).

I am patching the code with `if`-blocks and the code is getting messing and ugly, How can I do this in a clean, rails way?

@JTG suggested using `merge`, but apparently it don't work in a nested way (or for more of three tables/models):

```
Started GET "/api/products.json?order=total_cost&page=1&per_page=18" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-20 09:27:29 -0500
Processing by ProductsController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"order"=>"total_cost", "page"=>"1", "per_page"=>"18"}
Geokit is using the domain: localhost
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "roles"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  State Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "states".* FROM "states" WHERE "states"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "states"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 17]]
   (9.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" INNER JOIN "cities" ON "products"."geography_id" = "cities"."id" AND "products"."geography_type" = 'City' INNER JOIN "polygons" ON "products"."geography_id" = "neighborhoods"."id
" AND "products"."geography_type" = 'Neighborhood' INNER JOIN "cities" ON "neighborhoods"."cities_id" = "cities"."id" WHERE "products"."geography_id" = $1 AND "products"."geography_type" = $2 AND "cities"."states_id" = $1  [["geography_id", 17], ["geography_type", "State"], ["states_id", 17]]
PG::DuplicateAlias: ERROR:  table name "cities" specified more than once
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" INNER JOIN "cities" ON "products"."geography_id" = "cities"."id" AND "products"."geography_type" = 'City' INNER JOIN "neighborhoods" ON "products"."geography_id" = "neighborhoods"."id" AND "products"."geography_type" = 'Neighborhood' INNER JOIN "cities" ON "neighborhoods"."cities_id" = "cities"."id" WHERE "products"."geography_id" = $1 AND "products"."geography_type" = $2 AND "cities"."states_id" = $1
ERROR:  table name "cities" specified more than once
 -- Clase:
```

Comment: Can you show us the associations a `User` has? You speak of state, but show cities and neighborhoods (that is not how you spell that --aaaarrgghh), which I assume are already `has_many :through` the state a user can work on?

Comment: @nathanvda  Which is the correct way of spelling it?

Comment: @nathanvda  I will edit the question for showing the `User` model

Comment: Could you update your User class to include all associations including `products`, `cities` and `neighborhoods`?

Comment: @jokklan that's all the code in `User`, the `products` `belongs_to` the `geography` and the `User` `belongs_to` `State` That's it. Do you think that I am missing some associations?

Comment: Ok sorry, misread a part of the question :) In your example query, is a table called `polygons`, what is that?

Comment: @jokklan it is a mistake, `polygons` is `neighborhoods` I will edit that in this moment...

Comment: @jokklan Could you post your answer?

Comment: @jokklan are you there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use merge will combine the queries with `AND` and what you need is a SQL `OR` query. That is unfortunately not supported by any ActiveRecord method. You can use [arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) to create this query, but as it will be very complex and contain a lot of subqueries do I find it easier to just find the id's you need with normal queries and then use those.

To do that can you implement something like this in `State`.

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities
  has_many :neighborhoods, through: :cities

  has_many :products, as: :geography
  has_many :city_products, through: :cities, source: :products
  has_many :neighborhood_products, through: :neighborhoods, source: :products

  def all_products
    state_product_ids = product_ids
    city_product_ids = city_products.pluck(:id)
    neighborhood_product_ids = neighborhood_products.pluck(:id)
    all_product_ids = [state_product_ids, city_product_ids, neighborhood_product_ids].flatten.uniq

    Product.where(id: all_product_ids)
  end
end
```

You can now query a user for all products like this `user.state.all_products`.

Answer (score 1):

A polymorphic association is not suited optimally for these relationships...

[You can use a nested `has_many`.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#highlighter_453650)

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities
  has_many :products, through: :cities
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :neighborhoods
  has_many :products, through: :neighborhoods
end

class Neighborhood < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :neighborhood
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
end
```

Then you should be able to run `user.state.products`

**Even better** would be to add `has_many :products, through: :state` to user.rb so you could run `user.products`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is that you are assuming that product only belongs to neighborhood, and thats false in some cases. I mean product sometimes belongs to city and in other cases belongs to state directly, that is the reason I am using polymorphism. Any other idea?